# Textuals not appearing

Tags: html, css, background-image

the textual snippet "testing"for some reason does not render in a web browser, the only thing which is visible is the background image.  How can I solve this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        html { 
            background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .boundary {
            display:block;
            width:260px;
            float:left;
            color:#FFFFFF;
        }
        .margin-right {
            margin-right:10px;
        }
        <style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="boundary margin-right">
            testing.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `height:100%` to the `html`/`body` elements..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not closed your `</style>` properly

```
<style>
    html { 
        background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
   .......
   .......
</style>
```

Comment: @johnsonwi have you tried with </style> in the end of the style

Answer (score 0):

I cant reproduce the issue, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yMLvw/)

It´s working just fine are you sure the path to the image is ok?

```
    html {
        background: url(http://www.wallng.com/images/2013/08/image-explosion-colors-background-beautiful-263613.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .boundary {
        display:block;
        width:260px;
        float:left;
        color:#FFFFFF;
    }
    .margin-right {
        margin-right:10px;
    }
```

Comment: it was due to missing a / in the style tag